# Implicit assignment operator deleted for vector erasing?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have two vectors and I wish to compare them and delete duplicates. If I had two vectors `vecA` and `vecB`, I want to remove elements from `vecA` if they appear in `vecB`. Specifically, I want `vecA` to be passed to a method and mutated within that method.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class M {
    private:
        const char COL[8] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'};
    public:
        int aC, aR, dC, dR;
        M(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
            aC = a; aR = b; dC = c; dR = d;
        }
        bool operator==(M &m) {
            bool sameC = (aC == m.aC && dC == m.dC);
            bool sameR = (aR == m.aR && dR == m.dR);
            return (sameC && sameR);
        }
};

class B {
    public:
        std::vector<M> foo() {
            std::vector<M> vec;
            vec.push_back(M(1, 3, 2, 4));
            vec.push_back(M(1, 2, 3, 4));
            return vec;
        }
};

class K {
    public:
        void boo(B* b) {
            std::vector<M> vec;
            vec.push_back(M(1, 2, 3, 4));
            vec.push_back(M(2, 3, 4, 5));
            std::cout << "Size before: " << vec.size() << "\n";
            bar(b, vec);
            std::cout << "Size after: " << vec.size() << "\n";
        }
        void bar(B* b, std::vector<M> &v) {
            std::vector<M> vec = b->foo();
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++) {
                    if (v[i] == vec[j]) { v.erase(v.begin() + i); }
                }
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    B* baz;
    K var;
    var.boo(baz);
}
```

I get an error that `M& operator=(const M&) is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed`.

The problem code is that `const char` array; removing this bit of code, everything else works fine but why?

An expected output for this code would be:

```
Size before: 2
Size after: 1
```

Why is an assignment operator needed for the iteration anyways (for `erase`) and is there a workaround? What would the "default assignment operator" be in this case?

Comment: are you sure you are compiling the exact code you have posted?

Comment: BTW there is a runtime logic problem, the index to `v.erase` is out of bounds for some inputs

Comment: @MichaelKenzel my mistake, in making an MRE I omitted a couple of lines in error. I've updated the code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @gator well, your struct has a member that is `const`. That `const` there means that you cannot modify the member. Thus, you cannot assign to the member. Thus, the implicitly-defined assignment operator is defined as deleted…what would you expect copy assignment to do for this type!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class `M` has a non-static member variable `COL` that is an array of `const` things, so the compiler can't copy the contents of the array over.

Presumably you meant to make `COL` `static`, so it isn't a subobject of each `M` object?